# Laravel $product_cat is undefined?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to display my categories on my website in the template layout.. I get the error : "Undefined variable: $product_cat".

[homecontroller]

```
public function index()
{
    $bestseller = DB::select('select * from product where popular = ? AND p_status = ?', ['Yes', 'Active']);
    $hotpick = DB::select('select * from product where p_hot = ? AND p_status = ?', ['Yes', 'Active']);
    $product_cat = DB::table('pro_category')->where('pc_status', 'Active');
    return view('welcome', ['bestseller'=>$bestseller], ['hotpick'=>$hotpick], ['product_cat'=>$product_cat]);
}
```

[welcome.blade.php]

```
@foreach($product_cat as $product_cat)
                <div class="dropdown-menu full" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <center>
                <a class="dropdown-item full" href="#">{{$product_cat->pc_name}}</a>
            </center>
        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should use ORM queries whenever possible (If you publish your databases I can build you the ORM query)
2. You should return everything in the same array like this:

> ```
>  return view('welcome', [
>
> 'bestseller'=>$bestseller,
> 'hotpick'=>$hotpick,
> 'product_cat'=>$product_cat
> ]);
> ```

3. You should also give a different name to the alias, not the same name of the variable that you are running with foreach

> ```
> @foreach($product_cats as $product_cat)
> @endforeach
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Check the line where you are getting data from pro_category table. Make sure you are retreive data from it .

just dd($product_cat) and see

```
$product_cat = DB::table('pro_category')->where('pc_status', 'Active');
dd($product_cat);
```

In your view you are using `$product_cat as product_cat`
I would recommend you to use a different value such as

```
$foreach ($product_cat as $category){
  //Your code goes here
}
```

In your controller return view with data like this

```
 return view('welcome', [
   'bestseller'=>$bestseller, 
   'hotpick'=>$hotpick, 
   'product_cat'=>$product_cat
]);
```

Comment: i think the return view cant go more than 2 value.. did u find any possible way to make it?

Comment: Do this
return view('welcome', ['bestseller'=>$bestseller, 'hotpick'=>$hotpick, 
'product_cat'=>$product_cat]);